# find the pdf of a transformed random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the pdf of the random variable $Z=\dfrac{9}{(X+1)^2}$.

The pdf of x is $f_X(x)=\dfrac{(x)^2}{8}+\dfrac{x}{4}$.

Here is my attempt:

Start with the CDF of Z:

$F_Z(z)=P[Z<=z]$

$=P[\dfrac{x+1}{3}>=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt z}]$

$=1-P[\dfrac{x+1}{3}<=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt z}]$

$=1-F_x[\dfrac{3}{\sqrt(z)}-1]$.

then I would take the derivative and substitute $f_x$
$$
f_z=-(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt(z)}-1)'f_x(\dfrac{3}{\sqrt z}-1)
$$
This gives me $f_z=\dfrac{3(9-z)}{16(z^2\sqrt z)}$. 
the final answer in the book is $f_z=\dfrac{9}{8z^2}$

Comment: What is the support of $X$?

Comment: Innumerable typos, please correct them *carefully*.

Comment: support of x: 0<=x<=2 @max

Comment: Please correct $X=\dfrac{9}{(x+1)^2}$ into $Z=\dfrac{9}{(X+1)^2}$ (with $Z$ and $X$ instead of $X$ and $x$).

Comment: $\int_0^2 f_X(x) = \frac{5}{6}$. That's a problem.

Comment: Probably the function given for $f_X$ is actually the CDF. @OP: Sorry but how do you want to solve this successfully if you are so *careless*?

Comment: yes, the function given for $f_X$ is the CDF. Now I am getting the right solution.